# How can I change a Panda Dataframe so that the values are strictly between 0 and 1 while preserving the NaNs?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working on the Kaggle Titanic problem. I have a function that creates cross products of survival means by characteristics of the passengers. For SibSp by Embarked I get the following survival table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [[0.5,0.657,0.75, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN,0.556],
[0.372,0.375,0.667, np.NaN,0, np.NaN, np.NaN,0.362],
[0.302,0.438,0.375,0.364,0.3,0,0,0.336],
[0.343,0.506,0.478,0.364,0.214,0,0,0.377]]   
df_m = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[0,1,2,3,4,5,8,'All'],
                      index = ['C', 'Q', 'A', 'All'])
```

So the transpose of what I start with is:

```
Embarked         C         Q         S       All
SibSp                                           
0         0.500000  0.372093  0.302115  0.342920
1         0.657143  0.375000  0.468468  0.506494
2         0.750000  0.666667  0.375000  0.478261
3              NaN       NaN  0.363636  0.363636
4              NaN  0.000000  0.300000  0.214286
5              NaN       NaN  0.000000  0.000000
8              NaN       NaN  0.000000  0.000000
All       0.555556  0.362069  0.336049  0.376877
```

While the endpoint I want is something like:

```
Embarked         C         Q         S       All
SibSp                                           
0         0.500000  0.372093  0.302115  0.342920
1         0.657143  0.375000  0.468468  0.506494
2         0.750000  0.666667  0.375000  0.478261
3              NaN       NaN  0.363636  0.363636
4              NaN  0.000100  0.300000  0.214286
5              NaN       NaN  0.000100  0.000100
8              NaN       NaN  0.000100  0.000100
All       0.555556  0.362069  0.336049  0.376877
```

I want to restrict the rates to values strictly between 0 and 1, while preserving the NaNs. I've tried two ways with a loop:

```
for i in df_m.columns:
    for j in df_m.index:
        p_hat.at[i, j] = max(min(df_m[i, j], 0.999), 0.001)
```

and replacing '.at' in the last line with '.loc'. Both these approaches threw KeyError: (0, 'C') from the first column and index.

Another approach I took was to concatenate and take max(value, .001) and min(value, .999):

```
smalls = pd.DataFrame(0.001*np.ones(df_m.shape)) 
bigs   = pd.DataFrame(0.999*np.ones(df_m.shape)) 
smalls.columns = df_m.columns
bigs.columns = df_m.columns
smalls.index = df_m.index
bigs.index = df_m.index
p_hat1 = pd.concat([df_m, bigs]).groupby(level=0).min()
p_hat  = pd.concat([p_hat1, smalls]).groupby(level=0).max()
```

This had the side effect of converting the NaNs to 0.999.
At a later step, I want to combine the rates and counts and calculate the 95% confidence intervals for graphing. At that stage, I don't want to show the NaNs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the difference between the transpose and what you want? They look like the same dataframes to me...

Comment: Oh, is the only difference that you add 0.0001 to cells that are 0?

Comment: It doesn't show in this example but I also replace values of 1.0 with 0.999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df_m[df_m.eq(0)] = 0.0001
print(df_m.T)

# Output
         C       Q       A     All
0    0.500  0.3720  0.3020  0.3430
1    0.657  0.3750  0.4380  0.5060
2    0.750  0.6670  0.3750  0.4780
3      NaN     NaN  0.3640  0.3640
4      NaN  0.0001  0.3000  0.2140
5      NaN     NaN  0.0001  0.0001
8      NaN     NaN  0.0001  0.0001
All  0.556  0.3620  0.3360  0.3770
```

**Update**

> It doesn't show in this example but I also replace values of 1.0 with 0.999

Prefer `clip`

```
df_m = df_m.clip(lower=0.001, upper=0.999)
```

Comment: That is just what I wanted.  Thanks.